# Quantify preference: better, similar, worse

Tags: statistics

I am asking a sample of men to compare the perceived sharpness of two blades (A and B). One blade may be only sharper, duller, or similar to the other. How do I make sense of the following examples:

- 0% rate A sharper, 100% rate both similar, 0% rate B sharper
- 50% rate A sharper, 50% rate B sharper.

The first example sample above confidently thinks the blades are the same while the second sample disagree. But are the results statistically equivalent? Similarly:

- 50% rate A sharper, 25% rate both similar, 25% rate B sharper
- 25% rate A sharper, 75% rate both similar, 0% rate B sharper

Is A perceived to be 25% sharper than B in both cases?

Mathematically, how can I express that the last example is primarily similar with a sharper tendency (for A)?

Comment: Your final example does not add up to $100\%$.  Perhaps you intended "25% rate A sharper, 75% rate both similar, 0% rate B sharper"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by equivalent.  You can certainly say:

- In the first example, both times as many men rated A shaper as rated B sharper
- In the second example, more men rated A sharper than rated B sharper and the difference represented $25\%$ of the men

but you could also say

- In the first example, there was more disagreement among the men about sharpness in the second sample than in the first sample
- In the second example, there was more disagreement among the men about sharpness in the first sample than in the second sample

Statistics can measure several things, including the centre of a sample and the dispersion around that centre.  Equivalence is about whether the things that matter to you in this particular case are the same.

Comment: While the difference between A and B in the second set of results are the same 25%, the lowest set includes a large percent who rate the blades similar. I'm hoping to be able to capture both how much more sharp as well as the tendency toward similar. Shouldn't I be able to predict where a new random set of participants would likely rate the same blades? Is there a standard model or curve?

Comment: Suppose (30%, 50%, 20%). It would be correct to say that "10% more men rated A sharper than B" and "50% of men perceived A as similar to B", but is there such a thing as 60% greyness? ( asb(sharper - duller) + similar ): Can I say that the blade is "rated 10% sharper but overall 60% similar" (or something like that)?

Answer (score 0):

Alex and I have already discussed this via emails, but I thought I would post my thoughts here to hopefully stimulate more conversation on the topic....

This may not be statistically valid, but in the past I have formulated similar data as a net ratio (perhaps there is a better term?) similar to:

**netSharper / (netSharper + equallySharp)**

where netSharper equals the number who thought it sharper, minus the number who thought it duller ... or **netSharper = sharper - duller**

So, from the four examples, and supposing a total of 100 total survey results for each:

**Example 1:**

netsharper = 0 - 0 = 0

0 / (0 + 100) = 0

**Example 2:**

netsharper = 50 - 50 = 0

0 / (0 + 0) = can't divide by zero, so can't be expressed as a ratio ... but it is still a case where neither is sharper

**Example 3:**

netsharper = 50 - 25 = 25

25 / (25 + 25) = 25/50 = 0.5

perhaps expressed as a net 50% of responses found Blade A to be sharper than Blade B

**Example 4:**

netsharper = 25 - 0 = 25

25 / (25 + 75) = 25/100 = 0.25

perhaps expressed as a net 25% of responses found Blade A to be sharper than Blade B

I realize that this may be overly simplified, and I would also like to know if there is a better way of calculating and expressing this kind of data....